# Possible implications of points, planes, and planes having no actual "size".

Tags: geometry

Even though we depict points, lines, and planes with some sort of thickness when drawn, they are said to have no thickness whatsoever.

Is there any paradoxical or interesting implications of this property of these three geometric objects?

Moreover, all geometric objects are said to consist of points. How do we prove or demonstrate/ justify that lines and planes have infinitely many points. Or do we simply use our intuition/axiom to justify these claims?